# Authorization required for filter messages by ID

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm trying to use the sendgrid api to filter messages based on ID. I have the following code:

```
try {
    client.setApiKey(process.env.SendGridKey);

    const request = {
      url: `/v3/messages/${req.params.mail_id}`,
      method: "GET",
    };

    await client
      .request(request)
      .then(([response, body]) => {
        context.res = {
          body,
        };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  } catch (error) {
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
    };
  }
```

I'm getting a 400 error saying:

```
[{"message":"authorization required"}]
```

The API key is correct, and is being used. I have other methods written like this and they all seem to be working fine.

What could be the issue here? The code I'm using is mostly the same as in the sendgrid API reference.

Comment: await client.setApiKey(process.env.SendGridKey); ?

Comment: Good suggestion, still getting the same error tho

Answer (score 0):

Hey make sure you are subscribed to the "Extended Email Activity History" add on. It gives you access to the to api endpoints:
https://sendgrid.com/solutions/add-ons/30-days-additional-email-activity-history/